# Is there a way to take the values of a dictionary and match them up with a list collected letters?

Tags: python-3.x, function, import

Currently working on a homework assignment and I am completely stuck. Here is the problem:

Create a Python program that accepts user input to determine the average of 4 letter grades while
dropping the lowest grade. Display the lowest and the average.

1. Create a python program in a directory named L04_HW that accepts 4 letter grades A+ through
   F (both lower or upper case) such as: a, B+, c-, D+, d.
2. Use two Python files. One named letter_grade_avg.py with a main function to run the whole
   program.
3. Use an import statement to load functions for processing the grades. The functions will reside in
   a separate file called grade_compute.py.
4. Use 4 or more custom functions. An example could be:
   a. main
   b. processLine
   c. gradeToNumber
   d. numberToGrade
5. Check if user inputs q or Q to quit. If so, then quit program.
6. After accepting 4 letter grade inputs, program shall display the lowest letter grade and the
   average of 3 grades after removing the lowest grade

At this point I have already created the main function in the first file, and have figured out how to make the code repeat after the first iteration.

My current problem now is taking the collected grades in the list that has been created, and using those assigned values in a dictionary to find the lowest letter grade and drop it from the list, and then find the average grade and print it as a letter grade.

Here is my code in the main file:

---

```
def main():
    done = False
    while not done:
        done = processLine()

## Process one line of input
## @return True if the sentinel was encountered or false otherwise
grade_list = []
def processline():

    for x in range(50):

        for x in range(1):
            grade_list = []
            print('Enter letter grades such as a, A, B+, c-, D+')
            grade1 = input('Enter the first grade or Q to quit: ').upper()
            if grade1 == 'Q': #will either take a grade and add to list or quit
                exit(0)
            else:
                grade_list.append(grade1)

            #will now take rest of grades and ammend to the list
            grade2 = input('Enter the second grade: ').upper()
            grade_list.append(grade2)
            grade3 = input('Enter the third grade: ').upper()
            grade_list.append(grade3)
            grade4 = input('Enter the fourth grade: ').upper()
            grade_list.append(grade4)

            print('You entered the grades ', grade_list)
            

            from grade_compute import gradeToNumber
            gradeToNumber(grade_list)

processline()
```

And here is what I have so far for the called function in the next file:

```
def gradeToNumber(grade_list):
    grade_values = {'F-':1,
                    'F':2,
                    'F+':3,
                    'D-':4,
                    'D':5,
                    'D+':6,
                    'C-':7,
                    'C':8,
                    'C+':9,
                    'B-':10,
                    'B':11,
                    'B+':12,
                    'A-':13,
                    'A':14,
                    'A+':15
                    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried unpacking the list and dictionary, I've also tried using an if statement to check if the list items are in the dictionary, but neither of those have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your gradeToNumber function to convert your grade list to a number list.

```
def gradeToNumber(grade_list):
    grade_values = {'F-':1,
                    'F':2,
                    'F+':3,
                    'D-':4,
                    'D':5,
                    'D+':6,
                    'C-':7,
                    'C':8,
                    'C+':9,
                    'B-':10,
                    'B':11,
                    'B+':12,
                    'A-':13,
                    'A':14,
                    'A+':15
                    }

    number_values =[]
    for grade in grade_list:
        number_list.append(grade_values.get(grade))

    return number_list
```